# Websocket with kraken closes after sending subscription for open position

Tags: javascript, websocket, private-methods, kraken.js

I am trying to subscribe to the kraken websocket API for the OpenPositions. I have sent a challenge request and receive the challenge , i also have signed it correctly with my secret key but it seems like once i sent the openpositions subsctiption request, the web socket closes directly with a code of 1006 and reasons ''.

I am writing in Nodejs using the native library websocket and event emiiter to emit data of "kraken-update"

this is the main file that i run:

```
const con = new Connection(key = keys.api_key, secret=keys.secret);
con.on('kraken-update', (data) => {
    console.log(new Date, "DATA", data);
    return;
});
const go = async(key, secret) => {
    console.log(new Date, 'connecting...');
    await con.connect();
    console.log(new Date, 'connected');
    await con.sendchallenge()
}
```

and here is the Connection class

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const EventEmitter = require('events');

class Connection extends EventEmitter {
    constructor( key, secret, challenge = '') {
        super();
        this.url = 'wss://futures.kraken.com/ws/v1';
        this.connected = false;
        this.challenge = challenge;
        this.lastMessageAt = 0;
        this.key=key;
        this.secret=secret;
    }

    disconnect() {
        this.ws.disconnect();
    }

    connect() {
        if(this.connected) {
            console.log("ALREADY CONNECTED")
            return;
        }
        let readyHook;
        this.onOpen = new Promise(r => readyHook = r);
        this.ws = new WebSocket(this.url);
        this.ws.onopen = () => {
            this.connected = true;
            readyHook();
        }
        this.ws.onerror = (e) => {
            console.log(new Date, '[KRAKEN] error', e);
        }
        this.ws.onclose = (e) => {
            console.log(new Date, '[KRAKEN] close', e);
        }
        this.ws.onmessage = (e) => {
            //console.log("MESSAGE ",e.data)
            setImmediate(()=>this.handleMessage(e))
        }

        // initial book data coming in on the same tick as the subscription data
        // we defer this so the subscription promise resloves before we send
        // initial OB data.
        return this.onOpen;
    }

    handleMessage(e){
        this.lastMessageAt = new Date;
        console.log(e)
        const payload = JSON.parse(e.data);
        if(payload.event === 'subscribed') {
            this.emit('kraken-update', payload)
            console.log(new Date, "SUBSCRIBED ",payload)
            return;
        }
        if (payload.event === 'challenge'){
            this.challenge = payload.message
            this.emit('kraken-update', payload.message);
            this.subscribeOpenPositions();
            return;
        }
        if (payload.feed === "open_positions"){
            this.emit('kraken-update', payload.message);
            return;
        }

        else{
            console.log(new Date, "UNDETECTED ",payload)
            return;
        }
    }

    sendchallenge(){
        try{
            let onReady = new Promise(e => e);
            const data = JSON.stringify({'event': 'challenge','api_key':this.key})
            this.ws.send(data);
            return onReady;
        }
        catch(e){
            console.log(new Date, 'ERROR SENDING CHALLENGE')
            throw(e)
        }
    }

    subscribeOpenPositions(){
        //how to sign challenge:
        //https://support.kraken.com/hc/en-us/articles/360022635652-Sign-Challenge-Web-Socket-API-
        console.log(new Date, `SUBSCRIBING OPENPOSITION WITH ${this.challenge}....`);
        try{
            const secret_buffer = new Buffer.from(this.secret, 'base64');
            const hash          = new crypto.createHash('sha256');
            const hmac          = new crypto.createHmac('sha512', secret_buffer);
            const hash_digest   = hash.update(this.challenge).digest('binary');
            const hmac_digest   = hmac.update(hash_digest, 'binary').digest('base64');
            this.ws.send(JSON.stringify({"event":"ping"}))
            this.ws.send(JSON.stringify(
                {"event":"subscribe",
                "feed":"open_positions",
                "api_key":this.key,
                "original_challenge":this.challenge,
                "signed_challenge":hmac_digest}
            ));
            console.log("SENT");
        }
        catch(e){
            console.log(new Date,"ERROR SENDING SUBSCRIPTION REQUEST")
            throw(e)
        }
    }
}

module.exports = Connection;
```

summary of what happened:

connnect to kraken future server => request challenge => handle challenge then request openorder subscription while handling challenge => websocket closes